# React hot loader not working with styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, react-hot-loader

I am using react-hot-loader version `3.1.3`, styled-components version `2.2.0` and react `16`. This is the error message i get in the console. I've tried downgrading styled-components to version `2.0.0` and downgrading react-hot-loader to version `3.0.0` but it still does not work and so i am using the latest version of those scripts.

> React Hot Loader: this component is not accepted by Hot Loader. Please check is it extracted as a top level class, a function or a variable.
>
> Click below to reveal the source location: ƒ StyledComponent() { classCallCheck(this, StyledComponent); return possibleConstructorReturn(this, _ParentComponent.apply(this, arguments)); }

I have one styled component like so:

```
const Li = styled.li`
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333`;
```

And at the top of my script i am importing styled like so:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
```

And here is my `index.js` file's content:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './assets/css/index.css';
import App from './components/App/App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';

const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Component/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

render(App);

if (module.hot){
  module.hot.accept( './components/App/App', () => { render(App) });
}

registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening due to [this](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md) issue of `react-hot-loader`.

Try to wrap the following portion of your code into a standalone component

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Component/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Then, import the exported component in `index.js` and place it between `AppContainer` tag.

**Note:** Hot module replacement doed not work with `styled-components v2.2.1` due to [this](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1225#event-1334523244) issue. As you are using `v2.2.0`, you should not encounter this problem.